# Send string from asp.net core controller to ajax in ajax call response

Tags: asp.net-core, controller, jquery-ajax

hi 
 I'm trying to send a string from controller to ajax in ajax call response. but my ajax doesn't get the string in response , and i see the raw content in browser.
Actually ,this is a simple example of my main project.
I'm using ASP.NET Core for server side programming.
here's my codes:
server side :

```
        public IActionResult addlink(string link)
        {
            return Redirect("/home/showlink?key=" + link);
        }
        public IActionResult showlink(string key)
        {
            return Content("this is content from 2nd controller");
        }
```

client side :

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="mainlink"/>
    <button id="btn">submit</button>
</form>
<script>
    $("#btn").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/home/addlink",
            data: {
                "link": $("#mainlink").val()
            },
            success: function (response) {

                alert(response);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                alert(err.Message);
            }
        }
        )
    })
</script>
```

what i see in browser :

[image: My raw data]

in main project i want to send a text from controller to ajax call succes ,just this, please help me :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to return Ok ActionResult:

```
   public IActionResult addlink(string link)
    {
        return Ok("/home/showlink?key=" + link);
    }
```

Comment: Has action `public IActionResult addlink(string link)` has [HttpPost] attribute? If it possible, post raw respone with you see in browser.

Comment: i posted that, for [httppost] attribute, i don't have problem to get data from ajax, i have problem to send response from second controller"showlink"

Comment: In browser development tool inspect you post request. I think all work accordance you code.

Comment: Have you tried ```RedirectToAction``` as opposed to ```Redirect```

Answer (score 0):

If you add ajax to the submit button in the form, you should prevent the default behavior of form submission.

```
<script>
    $("#btn").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/home/addlink",
            data: {
                "link": $("#mainlink").val()
            },
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                alert(err.Message);
            }
        }
        )
    })
</script>
```